# PHP/Proper use of includes in subdirectory

Tags: php, hyperlink, subdirectory

I have a sitewide include file that I include in pages in the main directory.  However, I have put a bunch of pages with a common theme in a subdirectory.  These pages need to reference the same include file.  I am now running into problems with relative links in the include file for things like images since they call different paths depending on whether the main file is in the main directory or a sub-directory.  For example, the link `"images/pic.jpg"` will work if the include is called from the main directory but will try to go to `"sub/images/pic.jpg"` if the include is called from the sub-directory.

I had solved this by using hard links that go back to the root as in `/images/pic.jpg`.  However, I'd rather not use hard links as they may break if the site is moved to another directory etc.

Do all your pages calling a given include have to be in the same directory?  Or is there some technique to get relative links in the include to work, even if the include is called from a sub-directory?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules - you can deal with your includes as you want, but you should endeavour to be consistent.

The largest site I managed had thousands of include files scattered through hundreds of subdirectories. We used absolute paths throughout, using one variable to denote the root directory, and then concatenating the rest of the path on as required. When we needed to move the files, we needed to change that one variable, and the whole site moved.

You can use relative links, but I found them a lot more confusing when you're trying to figure out what files are being called from where.

Answer (score 3):

For HTML content, please use this meta :

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.domain.ca/base/website/" target="_blank" />
</head>
```

This meta will apply to each link. So if a link is `img/blabla` and your are inside a sub-sub-sub folder, the loaded image will be base_href + the src ...

And inside PHP, set a variable at the beginning of the script and put it before every include.
 You could also write this variable before every image load and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

In smaller projects, a simple constant will do this job just fine: Let's assume you have 2 files, `/homepage.php` and `/contact/form.php`, that both files include a third file `layout.php` - the main files (homepage + form) are supposed to propagate their location relative to the root directory of the webserver via a constant:

homepage.php

```
<?php
define('WEB_ROOT', './');  // relative path to /
include('layout.php');
```

contact/form.php

```
<?php
define('WEB_ROOT', '../');  // relative path to /
include('layout.php');
```

layout.php

```
<img src="<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>images/pic.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, i would attempt to create a function (of sorts) that checks for your current working directory and then adds the appropriate path dimensions accordingly

```
<?php

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me what you're actualling looking for is the `..` directory command. This will say "go up one directory".

From /:

`include('includes/inc.php');`

From /sub:

`include('../includes/inc.php');`

---

This works browser-side too. You can use the .. in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Hell you can use it anywhere. In your command line, especially.

To be honest though, I'd use absolute paths and just set a constant referring to the path to the site. That way you can just append the path you want to the end of that constant for an absolute path.

Comment: the problem is that the include is called from a file in main directory and also a sub-direcory, so going up one directory means different things depending on where the include is called.  You may be right about absolute paths.

Comment: That's fine. If you have code inside your include file that refers to specific paths based on itself you can actually grab the path to the included file no-matter where it was included from: `__FILE__`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__FILE__` [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) with [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) (or `__DIR__` on PHP 5.3+) to build a path relative to the included file.

```
$image = dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/pic.jpg';
```

or

```
$image = __DIR__ . '/images/pic.jpg';
```